# Copying data from colored cells only in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel sheets and a macro, which takes one and should copy only the cells with a certain background color. The rest should not be copied, because I want to keep the formulas in the original excel. My code, which gives me error is below. The error is type mismatch and it corresponds to the if statement within the loop.

```
Sub Take_Worksheet()
Dim strPath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

MsgBox "Select the Comments sheet"
Dim wb As Workbook
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
End If

For i = 1 To 100
    For j = 1 To 20

        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) <> wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) And wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) = wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j)
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next j
Next i  


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of the cells when it errors? Error values perhaps?

Comment: Firstly, **`Option Explicit`** is your friend. Second, here is a different approach: can you not just apply a filter to only display the cells in your column that you want to copy? you can then easily copy and past the visible cells to your other sheet and then remove the filter

Comment: Option Explicit doesn't help.. I can limit if statement to only use color (wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)), but again it copies the whole sheet and I only need the colored cells in order not to replace other formulas.

Comment: `Option Explicit` Always helps whether it solves your issue or not. It protects you from using variables with the incorrect data type and is very good practice to get into.

Answer (score 0):

I join @SJR: type mismatch typically happens in case of error in some cells. You can handle this this way:

```
If Not IsError(wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j)) Then
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) <> wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) And _
                  wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j) = wb.Sheets("Comments").Cells(i, j)
    End If
End If
```

BTW: You should have `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Take_Worksheet()
    Dim wsSel As Worksheet, wbPath As String, wsCom As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, usrSelection As Long

    'MsgBox "Select the Comments sheet"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the Comments sheet"
        usrSelection = .Show
    End With

    If usrSelection <> 0 Then   'continue only if user didn't cancel
        Set wsCom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comments")
        Set wsSel = Workbooks.Open(wbPath).Worksheets("Comments")
        wbPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = 1 To 100        'or wsCom.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For j = 1 To 20     'or wsCom.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                If wsCom.Cells(i, j) <> wsSel.Cells(i, j) And _
                   wsSel.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243) Then
                        wsCom.Cells(i, j) = wsSel.Cells(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```